# Can't able to create a simple login page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/login' , to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: "sessions#create"
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger]='Invalid login id'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

views/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_with url: login_path, local: true do |form| %>
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.email_field :email %>
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.password_field :password %>
    <%= form.submit "LogIn"%>
<% end %>
```

```
Error: 
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #6):
5.def create
6. user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
7. if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
```

I still can't understand why is this happening.

tried everything to solve on my own but can't.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the [`form_with` helper with a URL](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#helpers-for-generating-form-elements), but not with an [instance of a class](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object). Which is perfectly fine in your use-case, but sets the `params` non-nested.

When you remove the `[:session]` nesting from your `create` method, it should work:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    # ...
```